# Swift Charts with logarithmic axis

Tags: swift, plot, charts

I want to draw a plot with a logarithmic X-axis. This is possible with CorePlot. However, the Charts package from Daniel Gindi [danielgindi/Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) seems to fit better in a Swift environment. Unfortunately this package does not support logarithmic X-axis.

There is another package Charts-log from Thierry [thierryH91200/Charts-log](https://github.com/thierryH91200/Charts-log) **Charts-log** which should extend Charts with logarithmic axis.
Compiling the Charts-log project leads at

```
 scatterChartView.leftAxis.logarithmicEnabled = logAxeOY
 scatterChartView.xAxis.logarithmicEnabled = logAxeOX
```

to the error message **Value of type 'YAxis' has no member 'logarithmicEnabled'**. Indeed, in the Chart package xAxis has no member logarithmicEnabled. But I expected that Charts-log would modify the definition of xAxis.

All comments which I have found are older than 1,5 years.

Are there any newer examples?
What is the trick to make the Charts-log example run?
Is there any example with logarithmic axis?